# Efficient way to delete files from server PHP

Tags: php, performance

So I'm writing a script to delete images from my server. Basically I have a table in my Database which contains a list of buildings and each building has multiple images associated with an `id`. I'm saving my images on the server in a single folder and each image has the following naming format:
`buildingID_imagename.jpg`. For example, if I have a building with `id`=`23`, my images in my folder will appear as `23_imagename1.jpg`, `23_imagename2.jpg`, etc.

Now, I know how to delete an image using PHP using the `unlink` function. However, to delete all the images, I need to check each file file name one by one, do a split string manipulation, check for the id and then delete. The issue arises when I have like 10000 images in that folder. This becomes an expensive task to do although it will work.

My question, is there a simple way to check the image name and delete it from the folder?

Thanks

**EDIT**
After typing this, I just thought of one possible way. Getting all image links from my database table into an array, loop through it and delete just those. Would that be a good method to do it? Of course, after I get the images into an array, I'm also deleting them from the table.

Comment: If you have the names stored in the database table you simply can check if the `file_exists()` and then `unlink($file)`. Preparing the names from the table into an array is a good solution instead of using file operations.

Comment: exec('rm 23_*') this will remove all files beginning from 23_

Comment: @Tyr That's what I was thinking to be a good solution.

Comment: @ponury-kostek That's interesting, is there a catch to using this one? It's so simple and awesome

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the dataset, check if file exists and remove the file.

Maybe execute it as a cron job in-case you think there could be thousands of file in this operation.

```
if(file_exists($fileName)){
    unlink($fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the

`<? array_map ('unlink',glob('23_imagename*.jpg')); ?> // this example deletes all files with .jpg extension that starts with 23_imagename`

With the glob function you can apply regex to efficiently find files that you want to delete

http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php